# Create a slider bar with 2 thumbs in Avalonia

Tags: c#, avalonia

I am looking to create a slider bar like this:  [slider bar with 2 thumbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfO8J.png)  In c# on Avalonia

I tried this:

```
        <Slider Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 0, 65, 0" Height="35" Width="150" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="50" />
```

But it's for a single thumb